# Payara ldap login failed

Tags: ldap, payara

i migrate a Glassfish3.1.2.2 Application on a Payara 4.1.1.154.

Everything works fine, but the Login over ActiveDirectory doesn´t work.

The Exception is:

```
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: LDAP bind failed for CN=x,OU=Power-User,OU=UrsaUsers,"x".
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.findAndBind(LDAPRealm.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule.authenticate(LDAPLoginModule.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: LDAP bind failed for CN=Dominik Christ,OU=Power-User,OU=UrsaUsers,"dc=ursa-chemie,dc=de".
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.findAndBind(LDAPRealm.java:503)
    ... 50 more
Warnung:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: LDAP bind failed for CN=x,OU=Power-User,OU=UrsaUsers,"x,dc=de".
```

The Configurations are the same as on the other Glassfish instances, On Glassfish the login is successfull, only on Payara it doesn`t work.

Comment: Does this also fail on GlassFish 4.1.1?

Comment: no, it works on GlassFish 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the code and  unfortunately the error coming back from LDAP is swallowed but is logged. Can you set the Logger javax.enterprise.system.core.security to FINEST log level.

The code that is failing within Payara Server is below. However this code is no different from the code in GlassFish 4.1.1

```
private boolean bindAsUser(String bindDN, char[] password)
    {
        boolean bindSuccessful=false;

        Properties p = getLdapBindProps();

        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindDN);
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, new String(password));

        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(p);
            bindSuccessful = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (_logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
                _logger.finest("Error binding to directory as: " + bindDN);
                _logger.finest("Exception from JNDI: " + e.toString());
            }
        } finally {
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {}
            }
        }
        return bindSuccessful;
    }
```